# Horizontal nav bar

Tags: html

Trying to do something similar to MenuItem in ASP, but in HTML instead - how can I do this without tables?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a structure like:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Menu Item 1</li>
    <li>Menu Item 2</li>
    <li>Menu Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

And then using CSS you can float the li tags left:

```
<style>
    #menu li { float: left;}
</style>
```

View this link for a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/4Sag4/

Comment: You an also use `display: inline` instead of float (I prefer it personally)

Comment: Is it also possible to put a border around each menu item, so it looks like a button? :)

Comment: @tom - Use the CSS `border` attribute.